# Ejecutar una función al hacer enter con el teclado

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría poder ejecutar la función haciendo un <kbd>enter</kbd> sea en el pc o en celular sin tener que dar necesariamente click al botón que lleva el `onclick`.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto sin alterar tanto el código?

```js
function agregar(){
  var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```css
#result{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Texto...">
<button onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta es la manera de activar un botón cuando hace <kbd>Click</kbd> en <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Agregué `id="myBtn"` al botón y el siguiente ***JavaScript:***

```js
function agregar(){
var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = txt;
}
var input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

```css
#result{
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
background-color: red;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Texto...">
<button id="myBtn" onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>


<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Al input agrégale el evento `onkeyup`, y asígnale una función que compruebe si la tecla presionada fue un `enter` y de ser así que llame la función `agregar()`

```js
function enter(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
         agregar();
    }
}
function agregar(){
    var txt = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```css
#result{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="text" type="text" onkeyup="enter(event)" placeholder="Texto...">
<button onclick="agregar()">Agregar</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>

</body>
</html>
```